# Hibernate:How to check whether query is inserted in database as none of the method save(),saveorupdate() does not return any thing

Tags: hibernate

Want to use save instead of executeUpdate.

query=session.createSQLQuery("insert into merchant_profile(userid, merchant_code, merchant_name, status, phone_number, " +
                        "fax_number, email_id, activation_date, expiration_date,associated_group) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                query.setParameter(0, userId);
                query.setParameter(1, dto.getMerchantCode());
                query.setParameter(2, dto.getName());
                query.setParameter(3, dto.getStatus());
                query.setParameter(4, dto.getPhoneNumber());
                query.setParameter(5, dto.getFaxNumber());
                query.setParameter(6, dto.getEmailId());
                query.setParameter(7, dto.getActivationDate());
                query.setParameter(8, dto.getExpirationDate());
                query.setParameter(9, dto.getAssociatedGroup());

```
            int rec1=query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: So, you save(), then commit the transaction some time later, and if you get no exception, then your saved entity will be inserted in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If during the flush(), the db update failed because of some contraint violation exception then you'll be instantly notified.

If you're using optimistic locking @Version then the update will use it during the update/where version=? statement.

The org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister#check method is the one checking the expected row count against the updated row count.

So, you don't need to worry about it, Hibernate takes care of it behind the scenes.